# Gini coefficient in panel data

Tags: r, transform, panel, gini

I have a grouped data structure (different households answering a weekly opinion poll) and I observe them over 52 weeks (in the example below four weeks). Now I want to indicate the value of a household at a given point in time using the gini coefficient. In this case, the value of a household participating in the poll should be higher, if the household didn't participate in the past weeks. So a household always answering the poll should have a lower gini coefficient in a given week than a household answering every 4 weeks.

The data structure is as follows:

```
    da_poll <- data.frame(household = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4), week = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4), participation = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0))
    da_poll
       household week participation
    1          1    1             1
    2          1    2             1
    3          1    3             1
    4          1    4             1
    5          2    1             0
    6          2    2             0
    7          2    3             0
    8          2    4             1
    9          3    1             0
    10         3    2             1
    11         3    3             0
    12         3    4             1
    13         4    1             1
    14         4    2             1
    15         4    3             1
    16         4    4             0
```

1 indicates participation, 0 no participation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways. They all use function `Gini` in package `DescTools`.

```
library(DescTools)
```

**Base R**

```
tapply(da_poll$participation, da_poll$household, Gini)
#        1         2         3         4 
#0.0000000 1.0000000 0.6666667 0.3333333
```

Or, another base R way.

```
aggregate(participation ~ household, da_poll, Gini)
#  household participation
#1         1     0.0000000
#2         2     1.0000000
#3         3     0.6666667
#4         4     0.3333333
```

**`dplyr`**

```
library(dplyr)

da_poll %>% 
  group_by(household) %>%
  summarise(gini = Gini(participation))
## A tibble: 4 x 2
#  household  gini
#      <dbl> <dbl>
#1         1 0    
#2         2 1    
#3         3 0.667
#4         4 0.333
```

**Edit.**

To have one `Gini` coefficient value per row of the original data set, not an aggregate, use `ave` intead of `tapply` and `mutate` instead of `summarise`.

**With base R**

```
da_poll$gini <- ave(da_poll$participation, da_poll$household, FUN = Gini)
```

**`dplyr` solution**

```
da_poll %>% 
  group_by(household) %>%
  mutate(gini = Gini(participation))
```

Comment: Thanks, are there possibilites to have one gini coefficient for every household for every week? I am looking for something like that, because I do not want to have the variable at aggregated level.

Comment: @Scijens Yes, there are. Either with `ave` instead of `tapply` or `dplyr::mutate`. Will edit.

Comment: Thanks for the very good help. Unfortunately, this was not what I am looking for. It's still the same value for each household for each week. I would like to have it varying over the weeks. Fro my research, gini coefficient cannot do that. I'd better use generalized entropy. Maybe I have to ask a separate question on this? Thanks very much for your effort!

Comment: @ScijensThe problem seems to be that there is no `week` column. How can it vary by week then? The code above can be made to vary by *any* number of columns.

Comment: Yes, okay, I see - I will definitely add that. If you have any ideas how to then find a metric for every observation, I am very much looking forward to your answer. Thank you.